# retrieve an sql request that contains html html tags

Tags: html, mysql, cakephp-2.0

Cakephp 2.4.1

table: articles
field: id;title;content;slug

Hi everyone!
In my database I have some contents that I want to retrieve that contains some html tags

.
But nothing appears when I want to load a page but when I remove those tags the content loads.

in my controller

```
public function index(){
$articles = $this->Article->find('all');
$this->set('articles', $articles);
// debug($posts);
// die();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($articles)`?

Comment: thanks cale_b! I don't know what went wrongs but now everything is working

Answer (score 0):

I did restart mysql

```
rcmysql stop
rcmysql start
```

and then everything is back to normal.